# In IBM z are display files (dspf) like in IBM i?

Tags: mainframe

In an IBM i/AS400 there are display files (DSPF) which is used to design / create screens.
DSPF (display file) in AS/400 is a file with definitions to format a screen to show and to receive data.

Are there similar files in zOS?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens : DSPF (display file) in AS/400 is a file with definitions to formatting a screen to show and to receive data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Screens on z/OS are specific to a subsystem.

In [ISPF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=i-overview-ispf) you would use [Dialog Tag Language and/or panel definition statements](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-panel-definition-statement-guide) to create a screen (ISPF calls it a panel).

In [CICS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6) you would use [Assembler macros to create a BMS map](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=support-creating-map) (the screen).

In [IMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.2.0) you would use [Message Format Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.2.0?topic=tm-ims-message-format-service) to create a screen.

As indicated in @SteveIves answer, there exist products to "paint" a screen.

All of the above are used to create [3270](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3270) screens; these days of course almost all 3270 devices are emulated.  This is not the only way to create a user interface for a z/OS application.  CICS, for example, understands http and it is relatively common to have a web interface to a CICS application.

Comment: I just take a look at the Dialog tag language and it seems quite close to a screen definition file, and the BMS map as well. The MFS seems more complicated. I will dig a little bit more on these options. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There are no such files by default in z/OS. There are software products that have screen definitions - ISPF and Telon being 2. ISPF (Interactive System Productivity Feature) is the ‘default’ UI under TSO and you can create your own screens, but these are not dsp files.

Telon is (I think) some sort of screen layout/definition utility used to create applications running under IBM’s CICS. These are also not dsp files.

Answer (score 1):

I won't duplicate @cshneid or @steve_ives answers but will provide some context.  IIRC Display Files are more than screen mapping and include definitions for processing the data to be presented so they are more akin to a fuller programming paradigm than just mapping.

I'm not aware of a feature that incorporates **both mapping of data and processing** of files.  This is accomplished based on the runtimes (CICS, IMS, etc.) for 3270 streams.  Generally this is a combination of the mapping tools mentioned along with a programming language like COBOL, C, or other that are compatible with the runtime.

The closest I think you come is Dialog Manager in the TSO runtime which does have some data management capability but tends to be used for system level work and not user applications which are generally relegated to CICS, IMS, WAS, ...

Comment: CICS exists in IBM i as well, but it seems less used than the CICS from IBM z.